# Meaning "Colay with mSATA"

Tags: communication, bus, pcie, specifications, sata

In a datasheet of a embedded device ([this one in my case](https://www.advantech.com/products/f910a32b-088c-4f15-8a94-f130f22bc1b5/aimb-290/mod_47ed41cd-c7ce-4a2a-a681-14a59d1ccacf)) what does it mean that the PCIe bus is conneceted to a socket that says "Full-size Mini-PCIe **(colay mSATA)**"

[image]

Comment: 1) the included link doesn't work. 2) "colay" doesn't seem to be a proper word, maybe it is an abbreviation. 3) **maybe** the "Full-size Mini-PCIe" connector also has pins for a SATA interface (for an mSATA SSD). Some of my Dell notebooks have this, the PCIe slot supports mini PCIe cards but also mSATA SSDs.

Comment: 1) Link updated, thanks 2) I know, it doesn't show up in any dictionary that I could  get, but if you google "colay mSATA" many datasheets appear 3) Ok, that was my suspicion but I haven't seen it in the real world, I'll do some tests whenever I get the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mini-PCIe and mSATA are two different standards but which use the same physical connector. However they are not intercompatible by default.

As far as I can tell, "colay" is probably an abbreviation for co-layout, or co-support, indicating that the slot simultaneously support both the Mini-PCIe **and** mSATA standards allowing both types of cards to be plugged in.

This is confirmed by reading the link you post to. In the table under "Internal I/O", it says "Mini-PCIe: 1 (full size, support mSATA)"